# JQuery variable only works if alerted

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, variables

```
url = 'test.php';
dynbid = barr[bkey];
dynbcell = bcellarr[bkey];
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    url: url,
    data: {dynbid:dynbid,dynbcell:dynbcell,},
    success: function(html){
        //alert(html);
        //location.reload();
        mybstringt = html;
    }
})
alert(mybstringt);//only works if alerted
mybstring = (window.mybstringt).split(';');
dynbnpc = mybstring[0];
dynbhid = mybstring[1];
dynbhp = mybstring[2];
dynbhpmax = mybstring[3];
dynbvalue = mybstring[4];
dynbname = mybstring[5];
dynbtobuild = mybstring[6];
dynbtobuildat = mybstring[7];
dynbcell = mybstring[8];
dynbimg = mybstring[9];
dynbtype = mybstring[10];
```

The problem is, if I don't alert mybstrint, it won't be defined, and the code won't run from the very next line. I tried localStorage the variables just for the heck of it, but it only works if I reload the page once.

Comment: Move your variable assignment code in the success callback method

Comment: because your `mybstringt` is getting updated asynchronously.

Comment: What do you mean Mritunjay?

Comment: See also [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron) and https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Move your code inside the `ajax` success function

```
  url = 'test.php';
    dynbid = barr[bkey];
    dynbcell = bcellarr[bkey];
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: url,
        data: {dynbid:dynbid,dynbcell:dynbcell,},
        success: function(html){
        //alert(html);
        //location.reload();
        mybstringt = html;
        //alert(mybstringt);//only works if alerted
        /**Moved your code here **/
        var mybstring = (window.mybstringt).split(';');
        var dynbnpc = mybstring[0];
        var dynbhid = mybstring[1];
        var dynbhp = mybstring[2];
        var dynbhpmax = mybstring[3];
        var dynbvalue = mybstring[4];
        var dynbname = mybstring[5];
        var dynbtobuild = mybstring[6];
        var dynbtobuildat = mybstring[7];
        var dynbcell = mybstring[8];
        var dynbimg = mybstring[9];
        var dynbtype = mybstring[10];
        }
    })
```

Comment: Tried moving it, but no success. "ReferenceError: dynbimg is not defined"

Comment: convert all variables to `var dynbnpc = mybstring[0];`

Comment: Still the same error.

Comment: make sure you have enough ajax response.